# GnuPG with Powershell and wildcard for encrypting

Tags: powershell, gnupg

I am trying to encrypt all TXT files in a specific folder using the wildcard *.txt. When I run the PowerShell code in Admin rights I get this error message.

```
set-alias sz "$env:C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpg.exe"  
sz --encrypt --recipient "AABB (2048-bit)" "C:\Users\AA\Desktop\AABB_Test\*.txt"
```

*Error:*

```
**sz : gpg: can't open `C:\Users\AA\Desktop\AABB_Test\*.txt': No such file or directory**
```

*But If I choose just one of the txt file:*

```
set-alias sz "$env:C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpg.exe"  
sz --encrypt --recipient "AABB (2048-bit)" "C:\Users\AA\Desktop\AABB_Test\1_test_file.txt"
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should produce the result you desire.

```bsh
Set-Alias sz "$Env:SystemDrive\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpg.exe"  
$dirWithFiles = "$Env:SystemDrive\Users\AA\Desktop\AABB_Test"

Get-ChildItem -Path $dirWithFiles | ForEach-Object {
    sz --encrypt --recipient "AABB (2048-bit)" "$($_.FullName)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, the shell interprets the wildcard.  In cmd or powershell, each command interprets the wildcard using a library.